# *parser error* Unexpected symbol string, expecting class, delegate, enum, interface, partial or struct

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BaseCharacterClass {

    private string characterClassName;
    private string characterClassDescription;
    //stats
    private int stamina;
    private int health;
    private int magic;
}
```

`public string`(this is where the error is) `CharacterClassName{
        get{return characterClassName;}
        set{characterClassName = value;}
    public string CharacterClassDescription{
    get{return characterClassDescription;}
    set {characterClassDescription = value;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You closed your class too early

```
public class BaseCharacterClass {

private string characterClassName;
private string characterClassDescription;
//stats
private int stamina;
private int health;
private int magic;

\* } <-- Remove this *\ public string CharacterClassName{
        get{return characterClassName;}
        set{characterClassName = value;}
    public string CharacterClassDescription{
    get{return characterClassDescription;}
    set {characterClassDescription = value;}

} // <--- add this here
```

Comment: I had the same issue as this question, and your answer was the correct one. Thanks!